# How to write my data in json file?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testcase

How to write my data in json file? This is my try:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django_dynamic_fixture import G
import content.factories
from django.core import serializers
from content.models import UserProfile, Delivery
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class DeliveryTest(TestCase):
    def test_sample_data(self):
        for i in range(0,10):
            user = content.factories.UserFactory.create()
            print user
            for j in range(0, 50):
                delivery = content.factories.DeliveryFactory.create(user=user)
                print delivery

                with open("file.json", "w") as out:
                    data = serializers.serialize("json", User.objects.all() ) 

                with open("file.json", "w") as out:
                    data2 = serializers.serialize("json", Delivery.objects.all() )
```

Output (print): http://dpaste.com/hold/923339/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not actually writing your data, only converting to JSON. Call `.write()` on the open file:

```
with open("file.json", "w") as out:
    data = serializers.serialize("json", User.objects.all())
    out.write(data)
    data2 = serializers.serialize("json", Delivery.objects.all() )
    out.write(data)
```

Only open `file.json` *once*; every time you open it for writing with the `'w'` mode it'll be wiped first.

Alternatively, [get a reference to the serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/serialization/#django.core.serializers.get_serializer) and tell it to write to the open file directly:

```
with open("file.json", "w") as out:
    json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer('json')()
    json_serializer.serialize(User.objects.all(), stream=out)
    json_serializer.serialize(Delivery.objects.all(), stream=out)
```

which is more efficient.

Comment: I would prefer the later example. Introducing lots of variables (data, data2, data3?) when you don't need them is a bad habit. Almost as bad as having very generic variable names such as "data"

Comment: @baloo: I agree; but when helping out someone I prefer to reuse their code where possible first so it remains recognizable and they can more easily see what was missing. :-)